# Is there a way to get latest folder if folders are arranged as yyyy/mm/dd/hh in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, date, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have folders in s3 bucket structured as `YYYY/MM/DD/HH/file.txt`

I am using a Lambda function whose input will be `YYYY/MM/DD/HH` and the Lambda function will return content from the file.

Let's say these are valid folders (meaning they have `file.txt`):

- `2018/12/30/12`
- `2018/12/30/17`
- `2018/12/30/21`

If I were to input `2018/12/30/15` I want my Lambda function to print the file **from the latest folder before the user given time** so it would give me the file from `2018/12/30/12`.

I tried going back 1 hour and using `s3.getObject()` to check if that file exists.

Can I know how can I use `list_object()` to achieve this as the above method is not preferable?

I am using Lambda, boto3, python.

Comment: You would need to code this yourself in Python. Some questions: Are there any _other_ files in these folders, or is there only a single `file.txt` in each folder? How many folders are there (might there be more than 1000)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's helpful to note that there aren't really subfolders in a bucket.  Key names of objects may contain slashes and the S3 console infers some hierarchy.

> The Amazon S3 data model is a flat structure: You create a bucket, and
> the bucket stores objects. There is no hierarchy of subbuckets or
> subfolders. However, you can infer logical hierarchy using key name
> prefixes and delimiters as the Amazon S3 console does. The Amazon S3
> console supports a concept of folders.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

That said, you can get the list of all keys and then find the maximum key that is less than your target value.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The max_key value is a parameter, but it's not clear 
    # how the Lambda will be called so I just hard-coded it.
    max_key = "2018/12/30/15"
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    
    # Get the list of all items.  The default max is 1,000 so you may need
    # to do some paging if your bucket has more items than 1,000.
    all_items = my_bucket.objects.all()
    
    # Extract the actual key names into a list
    all_keys = [item.key for item in all_items]

    # Find the key that is the max() value less than the incoming key (max_key)
    golden_key = max([key for key in all_keys if key < max_key])
    
    result = f'The biggest key less than "{max_key}" is: "{golden_key}"'
    print(result)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(result)
    }
```